How to set different path for source files browser debugging?
I am using newest Angular project template in newest Visual Studio, I am setting baseHref in angular.json and after that I no longer get break point hit in VS or VS Code .ts files. I see that Chrome>Source files are under that baseHref path which does not exist physically and I don't want it to, I just want Chrome loading source files where they physically reside and that would probably fix the break point not being initialized issue.
I tried numerous combinations with sourceMapPathOverrides (Chrome and Edge) and none of them did anything.
